# How to keep virtualenvwrapper hooks under version control outside of $WORKON_HOME

Tags: python, version-control, symlink, virtualenvwrapper

I have a number of virtualenvwrapper hooks that I've created under `~/.virtualenvs` (the directory I've defined for the `$WORKON_HOME` variable).

I usually like to keep system files like this under version control - for example, I have a pretty highly customized bash profile `~/Repos/dotfiles/bash_profile` that is symlinked to `~/.bash_profile`.

However, when I tried moving the virtualenvwrapper hooks under `~/Repos/dotfiles/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/` and then symlinking them back to their original filenames under `~/.virtualenvs/`, I got the following error when I opened up a new Terminal window:

```
stevedore.extension error calling 'user_scripts': [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/Users/yiqing/.virtualenvs/postactivate'
stevedore.extension [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/Users/yiqing/.virtualenvs/postactivate'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 137, in _invoke_one_plugin
    response_callback(func(e, *args, **kwds))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 185, in invoke
    ext.plugin(args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/user_scripts.py", line 143, in initialize
    make_hook(get_path('$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR', filename), comment)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/user_scripts.py", line 124, in make_hook
    f = open(filename, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/Users/yiqing/.virtualenvs/postactivate'
```

Symlinking the entire directory (`rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs ; ln -sF ...`) doesn't work either, because then when I attempt to tab-complete a command, it gives back:

```
NOTE: Virtual environments directory /Users/yiqing/.virtualenvs does not exist. Creating...
mkdir: /Users/yiqing/.virtualenvs: Input/output error
```

Short of creating a Git repo in `~/.virtualenvs`, I'm wondering what other options I have for keeping these hooks under version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!

In my frustration, when I tried symlinking the entire directory, I accidentally indicated a relative path rather than an absolute path. Symlinking the absolute path (protip: `$PWD/` will tab-complete to the full path in OS X) will work :)